# Minecraft functions file structure

Tags: java, minecraft

I just found out that Minecraft supports coding custom functions. The guides I find show many different file structures over time. The latest I find for version 1.15.2 is below, but nonfunctional. Is it still correct?

```
.minecraft -> saves -> World -> datapacks -> RandomFolderName -> data -> namespace -> functions -> myfunc.mcfunction
```

and called it in-game with

```
/functions namespace:myfunc
```

-all I get is "Unknown function"..

p.s. pack.mcmeta is in datapacks

Answer (score 1):

Your path looks fine for myfunc.mcfunction, but you mention:

> p.s. pack.mcmeta is in datapacks

Your pack.mcmeta should be inside your specific datapack folder ("RandomFolderName") in your case. Since you can have multiple datapacks in the "datapacks" folder, each of which need their own pack.mcmeta.

After you move that over, it should work as a valid pack.

See [this tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yz2hYJ-0CTA&list=PLUtW5E6R_eqT5DZXmZgFYvKejzkMija72&index=5) for more info. The link should take you to video 5, which has a download for a blank template pack & explanation. The next couple of videos cover functions.